# How to trigger a filter of a BehaviorSubject stream when fromEvent("scroll') stream publishes?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, dom-events

**Preface:**
I have some incorrect procedural code with hopes, that it communicates intent.  I have a feeling that an operator like `flatMap` or `switchMap` will solve this problem; however, I still haven't made the mental leap in RXJS to really understand, how or when to use these operators.  So please bear with me.

**Description:**
I have 2 streams:

- `var scrolling = Observable.fromEvent(target, 'scroll');` which correctly captures the scroll event.
- `var sampleFiltered = this.sampleElementsActiveCollection` which is suppose to represent a stream of offsets that currently satisfy the rules/requirements: `offset < 10 && offset > 0`. e.g. *Elements are within 10 pixels from the top of the window.*

**Question:**
 When a scroll event occurs, How do I trigger a filter on the `var sampleFiltered = this.sampleElementOffsetData`? *(this is currently not triggering. )* Moreover, How would I clean up nested subscribes as they are currently just to communicate intent and not working at all.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollerElementsStoreModel } from './scroller-elements-store.model';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mh-scroll]'
})
export class MhScroll {
  lastKnownScrollPosition: number;
  ticking: boolean;
  sampleElementOffsetData: BehaviorSubject<number[]>;

  constructor(private scrollElementsStore: ScrollerElementsStoreModel) {
    this.lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;
    this.ticking = false;
    this.sampleElementOffsetData = new BehaviorSubject([100,350]);
  }


    isElementCloseToTop(target) {

      var scrolling = Observable.fromEvent(target, 'scroll'); //this works


      var scrollingSub = scrolling.subscribe(
          (x) => { // this works.

            // this section below is completely wrong; 
            // however, hopefully shows intent, that when 
            // scrolling.subscribe triggers I want to run this filter.
            var sampleFiltered = this.sampleElementOffsetData.filter((x) => {
              var offset = x + this.lastKnownScrollPosition;

              // return when element offset is within 10px.
              return offset < 10 && offset > 0 
            },this);


            var sub =  sampleFiltered.subscribe(
              (y) => {
               // Update DOM.
              }
            )
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('Error: %s', err);
          },
          () => {
            console.log('Completed');
          });

      this.ticking = false;
    }


    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event.target'])
    triggeredScroll(target) {
      this.lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

      if (!this.ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.isElementCloseToTop.bind(this, target));
      }

      this.ticking = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `sampleElementOffsetData` getting its data from? Who feeds it?

Comment: It will be a bunch of directives that will do their own math and pass up a payload thus setting the sampleElementsOffsetData.  I just set it by default to not make the code overly complex

Comment: You appear to have some type issues, the behavior subject emits an element `[100, 350]` when subscribed, but your subscribe handler does `x + this.lastKnown...` where `x` is `[100, 350]`...

Comment: In short, what exactly doesn't work? Does the `// Update DOM.` code block not get executed?

Comment: Sorry calling it quits for the night but.  I got closure in using mergeMap() operator instead of nesting.  The problem was the types too like you pointed out.  If you wanna post the answer I'll +1 best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems with my code:
1) there was a type error in the `BehaviorSubject`  Observable.filter will only iterate over Observables NOT an Observables values.

2) I was able to clean this up using the operator `.mergeMap`
[TL;DR: Map values from source to inner observable, merge output](https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/transformation/mergemap.md#tldr-map-values-from-source-to-inner-observable-merge-output)

```
var scrolling = Observable.fromEvent(target, 'scroll')
          .mergeMap(event => this.scrollElementsStore.elementUpdated.filter((event) => {
            var offset = event + this.lastKnownScrollPosition;
            console.log(event);
            return offset < 10 && offset > 0;
          }
        )).subscribe((x)=>{
          console.log(x, 'asdfasdf');
        })
```